# References for posing a walk cycle?

Tags: illustration, drawing, anatomy-for-artists

I want to make my own custom sprites for RPG Maker MV, and right now I'm using DesignDoll for proportions and such.

I'm trying to pose copies of the models so it looks like a walk cycle, but all the references I've been finding have either been 2D with very few stages, or if it's a 3D video the walk cycles don't look realistic at all, and I don't want to use those.

Does anyone know of a good reference to look at, either really in-depth videos or an online model that has a built in walk-cycle available?

Comment: I've been doing quite a few walk cycles recently and there're tons of these about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq9A5FD8G5w

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the angle, one option is that you download Daz3D that is free, and buy a walk cycle animation.

https://www.daz3d.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=walk%20cycle

There are different types of walk cycles, for example using high heels, a zombie walking, etc.

Some of them have videos, so you probably could use that.

Another brand is iClone's, that can be used on iClone and crazy talk Animator:

https://www.reallusion.com/ContentStore/csproduct.aspx?contentid=icmpackmmpv2wr

Crazy Talk allows you to put a pseudo-3D character, this is, a character with front, back, lateral and 45° views, so that is probably useful.

In my opinion, there are some good ones, if they are made with motion capture or a skilled artist. Sometimes the render looks ugly, but separate the look of the render to the walking cycle.

---

Another option is to make a simple youtube search: "People walking". Forget the cycle part.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=people+walking

You can find some details and complete your study.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_v7xtH9QWo

Try to use different words... Slow Motion? Sports? Champion? Businessman? Businesswoman? Sexy? Bad A..? This one is really interesting and funny: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEoUhlesN9E

They do not need to be all of the same people... it is a walking cycle, so study the cycle, not the model.